# Fetch rows and columns from two tables

Tags: php, sql, database, sqlite

I have two tables in my SQLite database. `cash` and `bank` both the tables contain the following attributes `(id, person_id, date, remarks, type, amount, balance)`
I want to fetch all the transactions stored in both the tables which has to be sorted by date, for that, I used `UNION` but I also want to get 2 separate columns for `cash balance` and `bank balance` if the record is coming from cash table then only the `cash balance` should change and `bank balance` should remain same.
Here is my code

```
$sql = "SELECT *, 'cash' AS mop 
        FROM cash 
        UNION ALL SELECT *, 'bank' AS mop 
                  FROM bank 
                  ORDER BY date DESC";

        $result = $db->query($sql); ?>
        <tr class="tab-head">
            <td>Date & Time</td>
            <td>Narration</td>
            <td>Mode</td>
            <td>Debit</td>
            <td>Credit</td>
            <td>Cash Balance</td>
            <td>Bank Balance</td>
        </tr> <?php
        if(numr($result)>0){
            while ($row=$result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) { 
                $date = date("d/m/Y h:i:s", strtotime($row['date']));
                $remarks = $row['remarks'];
                $type = $row['type'];
                $amount = $row['amount'];
                $balance = $row['balance'];
                $mop = $row['mop'];
                $type == "in" ? ($credit = $amount AND $debit = "-") : ($debit = $amount AND $credit = "-"); 
                $mop == "cash" ? ($cbal = $balance AND $bbal = "-") : ($bbal = $balance AND $cbal = "-"); ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $date; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $remarks; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $mop; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $debit; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $credit; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $cbal; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $bbal; ?></td>
                </tr> <?php
            }
        }
```

[image: This is what I'm Getting from the code above]
As You can see in the Output if the source table is cash it is showing the modified cash balnce and leaving the bank balance blank and vice versa.
What I want is I want to display the unchanged balance in the place of `-`
Can anyone please help me with any sql query or PHP code, both are accepted but I will prefer a proper sql query. Please Help

Comment: @RiggsFolly Have you even read the question before marking it duplicate. the link you provided have nothing to do with my question

Comment: But it is relevant to the code that is shown to us, which of course would not run. We can only operate on what you show us.

Comment: What are you talking about? This is not an answer to my question.

Comment: But that is the different thing. There no point in marking the question 
as duplicate. You should've edited my question or you should've suggest me to do so

Comment: @RiggsFolly This query *deliberately* uses constant string to differentiate the two parts of the UNION (see the Mode column in the output), and in any case SQLite does not use exactly the same rules as MySQL.

Comment: Oh silly me, I missed the SQLite bit. I do apologise

Comment: will you please help me to reopen it

Comment: Hay RiggsFolly. please help me to reopen this question as you marked it duplicate unnecessarily.

Comment: One of us is! It has been reopened already!! Try refreshing the page !!!

Comment: Okkay! thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Specify the columns that you want before doing the `union all`:

```
select id, person_id, date, remarks, type, amount,
       balance as cash_balance, 0 as bank_balance
from cash
union all
select id, person_id, date, remarks, type, amount,
       balance as cash_balance, balance as bank_balance
from cash
order by date desc;
```

Comment: Is there a reason for an anonymous downvote on what seems to me like a correct answer?